# Motherboard "Above 4G decoding" option automatically disables

Tags: motherboard, uefi

My motherboard ASUS Sabertooth Mark 2 has an UEFI option "Above 4G decoding".
But when I set it to "enable" and reboot, it is automatically sets itself in "disable" state.

What might the problem be?

Setup:

- motherboard: Asus Sabertooth Mark 2;
- cpu - Intel i7-4770;
- ram - Kingstone HyperX Beast 1600;
- video - NVIDIA GeForce 610

Comment: http://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1004170/

Comment: I saw this, but the question is about automatic switching to disabled state, not the meaning of option itself.

Comment: What is your setup, perhaps your configuration is incompatible with that setting so it reverts.

Comment: @Paul Setup:
 - motherboard: Asus Sabertooth Mark 2;
 - cpu - Intel i7-4770;
 - ram - Kingstone HyperX Beast 1600;
 - video - NVIDIA GeForce 610;